# Timer counter for auction products on the archive page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

The auction product timer counter works fine on the single store page, I want to add it to the store archive page as well, but it only displays for the first product in the store archive and does not show the rest.

Based on [Countdown timer until product sale ends on WooCommerce single product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625177/countdown-timer-until-product-sale-ends-on-woocommerce-single-product-page/62625573#62625573) answer code, here is my code attempt:

```
function sales_timer_countdown_product() {
    global $product;
    $sale_date = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_sale_price_dates_to', true );
    if ( ! empty( $sale_date ) ) {
        ?>
        <script>
            // Set the date we're counting down to
            var countDownDate = <?php echo $sale_date; ?> * 1000;
            // Update the count down every 1 second
            var x = setInterval(function() {
                // Get today's date and time
                var now = new Date().getTime();
                // Find the distance between now and the count down date
                var distance = countDownDate - now;
                // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
                var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                // Output the result in an element with id="saleend"
                document.getElementById("saleend").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
                // If the count down is over, write some text
                if (distance < 0) {
                    clearInterval(x);
                    document.getElementById("saleend").innerHTML = "The sale for this product has EXPIRED";
                }
            }, 1000);
        </script>
        <!-- this is where the countdown is displayed -->
        <p id="saleend" style="color:red"></p>
        <?php
    }
} add_shortcode( 'sales_timer_countdown_product', 'sales_timer_countdown_product' );
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To display the countdown timer for each product in the store archive page, you need to modify the template file responsible for rendering the store archive page. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

- Open your theme's template file for the store archive page (typically named archive-product.php or taxonomy-product_cat.php).
- Locate the section where the product loop is being executed. This is where individual product items are being displayed.
- Inside the loop, find the part where you want to display the countdown timer for each product (e.g., the product title, price, or a custom location). Add the following code snippet:

  ```
    <script>
        // Set the date we're counting down to
        var countDownDate<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?> = <?php echo $sale_date; ?> * 1000;
        // Update the count down every 1 second
        var x<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?> = setInterval(function() {
            // Get today's date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            // Find the distance between now and the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?> - now;
            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            // Output the result in an element with id="saleend"
            document.getElementById("saleend-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
            // If the count down is over, write some text
            if (distance < 0) {
                clearInterval(x<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>);
                document.getElementById("saleend-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>").innerHTML = "The sale for this product has EXPIRED";
            }
        }, 1000);
    </script>
    <!-- this is where the countdown is displayed -->
    <p id="saleend-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" style="color:red"></p>
  ```

This code generates a unique countdown timer for each product by using the product's ID (get_the_ID()) as a suffix for the variable and element IDs.

Save the changes to the template file, and the countdown timer should now be displayed for each product in the store archive page.

Comment: You don't need to copy that in a template, the first way is using the available hooks, which will give the same thing, without being obliged to add the code again, when the templates are updated. Only use the templates when you want to make changes to the template code itself, or if there is not a convenient hook.

Comment: LoicTheAztec, You are professors. I am proud that you gave an answer.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT